# How to trigger a process when an approval process has approved

Tags: process-builder, approval-process, process

I need to trigger a process builder when an approval process has approved a record. Instead of explicitly updating a field, is there a standard field update that happens with approval? (For which I can trigger the process)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle your scenario is to add a field to whatever object you're approving and have your final approval step be updating that field. Then, have your process kick off of that field update.

This field doesn't need to be complex, for instance a checkbox field called "Trigger Process" would work or having a picklist field with "Accepted", "Rejected", and "In Progress" with "In Progress" set as the default then "Accepted" as the final action for acceptance state and "Rejected" in the rejected state.

Most of the action you can take from approval processes relate to workflow rules, such as: tasks, outbound messages, etc. Unfortunately, there is currently not a direct way to trigger Process Builder from Approvals that I know of.

Comment: Pro Tip -- checkbox field would be better named as `Is_Approved__c`; triggering logic belongs in the PB or WFR conditions

Answer (score 1):

As of Spring '22, you can trigger a Flow from an Update Field action performed by an Approval Process.